# JVM Overhead Too Big

Tags: java

I had memory problems with one server. It's an amazon micro instance, so its memory is very limited (free -m says 603 MB). That's why I started tomcat with

```
-server -Xmx290m -Xms290m -XX:MaxPermSize=65m
```

However, the "java" process takes around 86% of the total memory, which is 518M. 518-355 = 163 MB overhead. That looks like a lot, and is suspicious, especially given than:

- a similar application ran on another jvm version on another micro instance doesn't have overhead this big
- the same application run locally gives just 40 MB overhead. Locally it runs in Windows 7, 64 bit.

The java version on the problematic server is:

```
java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.3.3.13.amzn1-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

The big discrepancy between the local runtime and the one on the server makes me exclude the option that there are some expensive off-heap objects (e.g. byte buffers) in the application (and I'm not using any of that anyway). I know that the JVM overhead varies, but having more than 1/2 of the heap as overhead sounds too big. So what could be the reason for that? Or is it a normal way of things?

Comment: Do you also add -server when you run it locally? What JVM do you have locally?

Comment: Oracle JDK, 7, 64-bit (I'm not on the home computer right now, so I won't be able to give more details for a while). I'm not sure about the -server switch, that's a good point. I'll try that.

Comment: how does it react without any switches? i.e the defaults?

Comment: fails with OOME. The defaults are not sufficient.

Comment: How do you know that you're seeing "overhead"?  And keep in mind that things like the length of your classpath or the size of your properties files can add up to a significant difference.  But Ralf's comments about 32-bit JVM and choice of GC algorithm are good ones.

Comment: What else, but overhead can it be? The perm size and the heap size are configurable and known (via jmx)

Answer (score 2):

The choice of GC may impact heap size overhead, since each GC scheme must set aside some memory to manage your heap. Also, on such a small VM, you may not benefit much from going 64bit. A 32bit jvm will take up less heap, even when using CompressOOPS, which should be on by default.
So play with your favourite garbage collectors, pick the one that gives the best mix of overhead and latency for you.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Setting -XX:+UseCompressedOops, and also adding headless=true improved things a bit. But still, 483 MB are used, where 350 are reserved for heap+permgen. Probably tweaking the GC will have additional effect, but the discrepancy between the windows and the linux jvms, looks strange.

Comment: if you want to be extra thorough, try these:
<br>
    -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
    -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal
    -XX:+LogVMOutput
    -XX:LogFile=jvm.log
<br>
then compare the output to look for differing flags between the two versions
<br>
Can you try Oracle Java at amazon?

Comment: (I can try Oracle Java, I guess, but it would take some time to make the deployment that I don't have now)